# How to check whether certain port is opened or block on any other servers from a dev box?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, telnet, ping

I am trying to connect to one of our staging Cassandra servers on port 9042 and 9160 here in our company from a dev box.. Through the code, I am not able to connect to it... The program gets hanged at my SELECT query..

So I am wondering is there any way to figure out from my dev box whether these two ports are either blocked on my Cassandra staging servers or not?

Below is the Cassandra staging server url which I am trying to connect from my dev box -

`sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com`

And my dev box machine url is -

`username-dyn-vm1-4.phx-os1.tratus.dev.host.com`

Can anyone tell me how to figure out what can be the possible reason to which I am not able to connect to it..

How to check from my dev box whether these ports are opened or not on my Cassandra staging servers?

**Update:-**

```
ubuntu@username-dyn-vm1-4:~/build$ traceroute sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com
traceroute to sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com (10.109.107.64), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.9.209.1 (10.9.209.1)  4.594 ms  6.628 ms  8.299 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  stgcass01-1.vip.slc.qa.host.com (10.109.107.64)  7.907 ms  3.312 ms  3.950 ms
```

This is what I got when I ran nmap -

```
ubuntu@username-dyn-vm1-4:~/build$ nmap -p T:9160 sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-13 20:01 UTC
Nmap scan report for sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com (10.109.107.64)
Host is up (0.0037s latency).
rDNS record for 10.109.107.64: stgcass01-1.vip.slc.qa.host.com
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9160/tcp open  apani1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.19 seconds
ubuntu@username-dyn-vm1-48493:~/build$ nmap -p T:9042 sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-13 20:02 UTC
Nmap scan report for sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com (10.109.107.64)
Host is up (0.0049s latency).
rDNS record for 10.109.107.64: stgcass01-1.vip.slc.qa.host.com
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9042/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

Does that mean port is opened correctly and there is no problem?

And with telnet I get this -

```
ubuntu@username-dyn-vm1-4:~/build$ telnet sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com 9042
Trying 10.109.107.64...
Connected to stgcass01-1.vip.slc.qa.host.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

ubuntu@username-dyn-vm1-4:~/build$ telnet sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com 9160
Trying 10.109.107.64...
Connected to stgcass01-1.vip.slc.qa.host.com.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried telnet from the dev box?

```
telnet sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com 9042
telnet sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com 9160
```

if you get a telnet prompt back, you have connectivity, if it hangs there the connection may be timing out, if the command fails outright you may have firewall rules preventing access. You can try 'traceroute sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com' to see the path the connection is trying to take.

Comment: It looks like you have access from dev to the staging server. Here are some ideas - 1) Since you are trying to establish a connection (as opposed to just pinging), make sure the staging server can connect back to dev and 2) eliminate asymmetrical routing as an issue. Check that the path that the staging server takes to reply back is the same one that dev took to initiate the connection, i.e. if you do a traceroute on both servers, they should go through the same firewall/load balancer (or nothing and just connect directly).

Comment: There is no requirement for the reverse route to be the same as the forward route. There's a paper by Vern Paxson that shows that 35%, or some such large proportion, of the routes used in the Internet are asymmetrical.

Comment: You are correct - In and of itself, asymmetrical routing will not cause issues as long as the route is correct (which i realize I did not phrase correctly above) From my experience, these different routes often cause issues where the gateways being used don't have the proper path to come back to the original host. So just something worth checking is that the route back from the destination to the host is sound - thanks for bringing it up!